# macro that will insert a space between words in an array

Tags: assembly, macros, x86, irvine32

I need to write a macro that will insert a space between each word in the final array. How could I achieve this and where must I initialize and call it.

**Desired output:** "Say Cheese Okay".

**Output so far:** "SayCheeseOkay"

My code so far:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
seq1 byte 'Sequence1 : ', 0
seq2 byte 'Sequence2 : ', 0
seq3 byte 'Sequence3 : ', 0
fin_seq byte 'Final Sequence : ', 0
s1 byte 'Say', 0
s2 byte 'Cheese', 0
s3 byte 'Okay', 0
s4 byte 30 dup(?)

.code
main PROC
    cld
    mov edx, offset seq1
    call WriteString
    mov edx, offset s1
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

    mov edx, offset seq2
    call WriteString
    mov edx, offset s2
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

    mov edx, offset seq3
    call WriteString
    mov edx, offset s3
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

    mov ecx, LENGTHOF s1
    mov esi, offset s1
    mov edi, offset s4

copy1 : movsb
    loop copy1

    mov ecx, LENGTHOF s2
    mov esi, offset s2
    mov edi, offset s4
    add edi, LENGTHOF s1
    sub edi, 1


copy2: movsb
    loop copy2
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF s3
    mov esi, offset s3
    mov edi, offset s4
    add edi, LENGTHOF s1
    add edi, LENGTHOF s2
    sub edi, 2

copy3: movsb
    loop copy3
    mov edi, offset s4
    mov ecx, lengthof s4
    mov al, ' '
    cld

c1:
    scasb
    je c2
    cmp ecx, 0
    jz quit
    loop c1

c2:
    cld
    sub edi, 1
    stosb
    jmp c1

quit:
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF s4
    mov esi, OFFSET s4
    mov ebx, 0

cycle:
    mov al, [esi]
    jmp exl


exl:
    movsb
    loop cycle
    mov edx, offset fin_seq
    call WriteString
    mov edx, offset s4
    call WriteString

    call Crlf
    call ReadKey
    call ReadChar

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Why do you reinit `edi` after `copy1` loop? (which can be replaced by `rep movsb`). Has it any purpose, or you just didn't think how to simplify the task? Because once you will "streamline" the `edi` usage, you can easily put space between by `mov al,' '` `stosb`. Watch in debugger registers and the code, what it actually does, and which parts are redundant. Fix: actually that would copy also the zero terminator, and put space after it, so instead of stosb you can do `mov byte ptr [edi-1],' '`. And why do you need "macro"? :-o .. avoid macros, if you are just learning assembler, not needed.

Comment: No special purpose, like you said, I done it that way, because I lacked the knowledge how to do it otherwise. I need macro simply because it is an assignment :p

Comment: ok, takes some time to pick the experience... for a start launch this in debugger and single step over it, trying to figure out how it works, how the final result in memory is stored/build up, and what particular instruction does in that chain. Making macro of single instruction is weird, I have no idea how I would turn `mov [edi-1],' '` into meaningful macro. Maybe the assignment asked for some more complex macro, or something. Either way, it's weird to ask you to write macro, if you are sort of lacking in the basics, macros are nice help to cut out small repetitive bits, but not for beginner

Comment: The assigment just says use macro... But thanks for the mov [edi-1],' ' , it gives me some ground on how to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 0):

The marco should look like this:

```
procedure MACRO ad1
    mov byte ptr [edi-1],' '

ENDM
```

and just call it after the copy1 and copy2 methods. And delete `sub edi, 1` in the copy1 method.

Comment: Try to not call macro procedure, they are different things. Procedures in source are actual machine code, which may be called, and will land in the machine code at the same place, where you have them in source (relatively to other code around). Macros are injected at the place, where you use them, so they are like doing a bit more complex "replace all" of the source text before compilation. So the name "procedure" does not say what that macro DOES, and it also has nothing with procedure. I would go with something like `WriteSpaceAtPreviousEdi` = chance to understand what it does after reading.

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing is, that with the way you defined `s1`,`s2`,`s3` in memory, you can "concatenate" the strings into single one just by this (this is not solution to your assignment, as it effectively takes all the work out of it, it's just demonstration how things in assembly can be fast, if the programmer carefully reasons about what has to be done and comes up with optimal algorithm first ... also it demonstrates somewhat more meaningful way of using a macro, although in my own code I would rather use procedure, unless some special performance reasons would made macro needed):

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
seq1 byte 'Sequence1 : ', 0
seq2 byte 'Sequence2 : ', 0
seq3 byte 'Sequence3 : ', 0
fin_seq byte 'Final Sequence : ', 0
s1 byte 'Say', 0
s2 byte 'Cheese', 0
s3 byte 'Okay', 0

.code

DisplayLabelValueEol MACRO labelStrPtr:REQ, valueStrPtr:REQ
    mov     edx,labelStrPtr
    call    WriteString
    mov     edx,valueStrPtr
    call    WriteString
    call    Crlf
    ENDM

main PROC
    DisplayLabelValueEol OFFSET seq1, OFFSET s1
    DisplayLabelValueEol OFFSET seq2, OFFSET s2
    DisplayLabelValueEol OFFSET seq3, OFFSET s3
    ; modify s1-s2-s3 memory to work as single concatenated string
    mov     al,' '
    mov     [s2-1],al       ; replace the original s1 zero terminator
    mov     [s3-1],al       ; replace the original s2 zero terminator
    ; display result
    DisplayLabelValueEol OFFSET fin_seq, OFFSET s1

    call ReadKey
    call ReadChar
    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

(unfortunately I don't have MASM + Irvine32 anywhere, so I didn't actually test it, let me know if this does not work).